# make tab active, if tab class has active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

need help with active class.

i use this code to create simple tabs. all works fine.

but i can't get this code to work with "active class" as i need.
the code now select the first tab and make him active.

i want to add by myself the active class code to the div like:

need help to make this work.

Thanks

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2' class='active'>
    <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab3'>
    <p>And this is the 3rd tab.</p>
  </div>
```

and here is the JS code. the problem as i see in the "$active"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.info-tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
      $(this.hash).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
      // Make the old tab inactive.
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $content.hide();

      // Update the variables with the new link and content
      $active = $(this);
      $content = $(this.hash);

      // Make the tab active.
      $active.addClass('active');
      $content.show();

      // Prevent the anchor's default click action
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your each loop, you are iterating using a selector .info-tabs

```
$('.info-tabs').each( //some stuff here )
```

But i dnt see any info-tabs class anywhere.
So check your html content first.